# bootstrap 4 image size display different

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

Please can someone tell me why the images  on http://urupema.pt/teste.aspx
as the same size but display different sizes. For instance samsung is very high
The code is the same for all the images.
Here is it

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3>Samsung</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <img src="imagens_marcas/samsung.png"  class="img-thumbnail" />
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                Impressoras Jato de Tinta, Laser, consumíveis...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The images don't have the same size.

Comment: solved the issue with car deck class. Now they are aligned independent of the image size